# SSIS Package - track calling job

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm looking for ideas on how to **automatically** track the job that calls the package.

We have some genric packages that are called from different jobs, each job passes in different file paths as parameters and therefore processes very different size files depending on the path.

In the package I have some custom auditing setup which basically tracks the package start time and end time, and therefore the duration of execution.  I want to be able to also track the job that called the package so if the package is running long, I can determine which job called it.

Also note I would prefer this automatic using possibly some sort of system variable or such, so that human error is not an issue.  I also want these auditing tasks built into all of our packages as a template, so I would prefer not to use a user variable either - as different packages may use different variables.

Just looking for some ideas - appreciate any input

Comment: You could have the job name passed as a parameter.

Comment: Yes this may be about the easiest thing to do but would prefer to not have to type the job name in as with the high volume of jobs here and the fact that a lot of the dba's just copy and paste jobs - these parameters don't always get set right

Comment: I just don't know that there's anything special about the way that SQL Agent runs SSIS packages that would provide the job name to the called package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use parent and child packages instead of different jobs calling the same package. You could send the information about which parent called it to the child package and then in the child package records that data to a table along with the start date and end date.

Our solution has a whole meta database that records all the details through logging of each step. The parent tells the child which configuration to use and log details against that configuration. The jobs call the parent package - never the child package (which doesn't have a configuration in the config table as it is always configured through variables sent in by the parent package. No human intervention necessary (except initial development or research when a failure occurs) needed.

Edit for existing jobs.

Consider that jobs can have multiple steps. Make the first step a SQL script that inserts the auditing information into  a table including the start time of the package, the name of the job that called it and thename of the ssispacakge being called. Then the second step calls the SSIS package and then make the last step a SQL script that inserts the same data only with the end datetime.

Comment: That seems like a good approach and makes perfect sense to me and may consider it for future development.

But for now looking for something easier.  We might want to apply this auditing to a bunch of existing jobs/packages

Comment: Thanks, just read your edit.  And that is a good approach as well.  Currentyl we have everythignthat you mention theere available through SSIS logging (to a table) - all except the job name, so probably will just pass the hard coded job name to the package

Comment: I just found the answer to my question - SQL Server Agent Tokens

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to set up a variable on your SSIS package as a varchar. Set the value to the value of the variable to @[System::ParentContainerGUID] using an expression when it starts. SQL Agent won't set the value, so when run as an individual job it will be an empty string. But if called by another package it will contain the GUID of the calling package. You can test for that value. You can use a precedence contraint to control the program logic.

We have packages that run as a part of a big program but sometimes we need to run them individually. Each package has an email on failure task but we only want that to execute when the package is run individually. When it is part of the big run we collect the names of all packages that error and send them as one email from the master package. We don't want individual emails and a summary email going out on the same run.